# A polynomial reduction from HAMPATH to LONG-PATH

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np-hard, hamiltonian-path

$\text{HAMPATH} = \{(G=(V,E),s',t')| \text{ G has a Hamilton path from s' to t' } \}$

$\text{LONG-PATH} = \{(G,s,t,k) |  \text{G has a simple path p from s to t, length(p) $\geq$ k}  \}$

I'm trying to prove a polynomial reduction, $\text{HAMPATH} \leq_p \text{LONG-PATH}$.

My thought was to take an instance of $\text{HAMPATH}$ and add exactly $k-|V|$ nodes and edges from $t'$ to $s'$, so i have an Hamilton path from $s=s'$ to $t'$, and a simple path(which is also an Hamilton path) from $t'$ to $t$.

I tried to prove that but i couldn't finish the proof and it seems that this is not good reduction.

any thoughts?

Comment: How long is a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: @Louis, obviously |V|...

Comment: please help me..