# What is wrong with my LP exercise (longest path cost for a graph)

Tags: graphs, optimization, linear-programming

I have to do a linear programming exercise  but i have some problems regarding the result. I have a graph with N nodes and E edges, that is not acyclic, and each edge is associated to a cost. I have also two nodes (marked as B and E), and I have to find the maximum path cost from B to E. Also, each edge can be used at most k times and the total cost of the path must be at most C.

I have inserted also the constraint regarding the balance of each node as follow (where E are the edges and x[i,j] tells me how many times an edges is been used, and the two nodes B and E):

$\sum\nolimits_{j |(j,i) \in Edges} x(j,i) -\sum\nolimits_{j | (i,j) \in Edges} x(i,j) =0$

$\sum\nolimits_{j | (j,B) \in Edges} x(j,B) -\sum\nolimits_{j | (B,j) \in Edges} x(B,j) =-1$

$\sum\nolimits_{j | (j,E) \in Edges} x(j,E) -\sum\nolimits_{j | (E,j) \in Edges} x(E,j) =1$

The objective function is:
$max \sum\nolimits_{(i,j) \in Edges} x(i,j)*cost(i,j)$

Other constraints:

$x(i,j) <= K \forall (i,j) \in Edges$

$\sum\nolimits_{(i,j) \in Edges} x(i,j)*cost(i,j) <= C$

When i run the LP solver the solution that it gives me, of course it includes a path from B to E, but also an other cyclic path that not includes nodes B and E.

Any suggestion?

Comment: 1) What is ampl? 2) Tool support questions are offtopic here. 3) Have you tried executing the algorithm yourself? That'll help debugging. 4) You can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Comment: AMPL is a only a tool, but i am interesting only in the contraints shown above and how can i change in order to make the model proper.

Comment: You should be able to go further in diagnosing this yourself.  The solution includes another path.  Well, does that other solution satisfy all of the inequalities?  See if you can articulate why you are you unhappy with it.  What additional inequalities could you add to rule out that unwanted solution?  Then, edit the question to include that information.  We discourage "please check my answer" or "please debug my answer" questions here, as they're unlikely to help anyone else ever again in the future.

Comment: Ok, now i'll describe all the model, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: This is roughly the equivalent of finding a cycle cover of a graph when you're looking for a Hamiltonian cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You are on a fool's errand: [Longest Path is NP-hard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/a-polynomial-reduction-from-hampath-to-long-path?lq=1), thus there *is no LP* for solving it.

Comment: If "each edge can be used at most k times" is to be non-trivial, then his problem must also allow re-use of nodes, in which case I don't see a reduction from his problem to the standard Longest Path problem. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer The reduction from HamPath only needs $k=1$, doesn't it? What am I missing? (We want to reduce normal Longest Path to this one in order to show that this one is hard, and $k=1$ seems to work as well.)

Comment: "each edge can be used at most 1 time" would follow _automatically_ from "each node can be used at most 1 time". ​ (I did have the relevant direction of reduction backwards.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: So is there no solution for my problem?

Comment: @Dan11 There is, but (as far as I can tell) probably not a fast *and* general *and* exact one. See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/dealing-with-intractability-np-complete-problems/1481#1481) for some ideas.